# [Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''Por favor llene todos los cam' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 8]

Tags: php, sql

Este es el código, estuve mirando bastante tiempo y no soy capaz de encontrar el error/errores. (Soy muy novato)
¡Gracias de antemano!

```html
   <?php
session_start();
include_once "conexion.php";
{
    if($_POST['usuario'] == '' or $_POST['password'] == '' or $_POST['repassword'] == '')

    {
        echo 'Por favor llene todos los campos.';
    }
    else
    {
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM usuarios';
        $rec = mysql_query($sql);
        $verificar_usuario = 0;

        while($result = mysql_fetch_object($rec))
        {
            if($result->usuario == $_POST['usuario'])
            {
                $verificar_usuario = 1;
            }
        }

        if($verificar_usuario)
        {
            if($_POST['password'] == $_POST['repassword'])
            {
                $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
                $password = $_POST['password'];
                $sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios (usuario,password) VALUES ('$usuario','$password')";
                mysql_query($sql);

                echo 'Usted se ha registrado correctamente.';
            }
            else
            {
                echo 'Las claves no son iguales, intente nuevamente.';
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'Este usuario ya ha sido registrado anteriormente.';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No veo ningún error de sintaxis en el código. El error que lanza hace referencia a un mal uso del String en php. Por ejemplo, en este caso, se refiere a que donde pones  echo 'Por favor llene todos los campos.'; estas acabando mal el string. Has copiado el script tal cual lo tienes tú o has cambiado algo?

Comment: ¡Hola! Está todo tal y como lo tengo.

Comment: 2 cosas , la primera las comprobaciones hazlas en el cliente, mediante javascript para comprobar si las contraseñas son iguales, para si ha rellenado algo, en el html del input del usuario con poner required, sobra. Las comprobaciones siempre van en el cliente.

Segundo, si haces la select * from usuarios where 'nombre' = $_POST['usuario'] and password = $_POST['password']

,la sintaxis tienes que corregirla Significa que encuentra registro,

Comment: @EduBw La primera, las comprobaciones desde el cliente se hacen por experiencia de usuario, por seguridad deben hacerse también desde el servidor ya que desde JavaScript todos podemos inspeccionar y saltarnos las comprobaciones. En cuanto a la segunda, no veo que la forma de hacer la SELECT pueda lanzar tal error.

Comment: ¿Por qué puede ser causado ese error entonces?

Comment: Haz una cosa, comenta la linea que te da el error (linea 8, donde haces el primer echo) y mira si te funciona, si te sigue dando error aqui postealo en un comentario, a ver que tal.

Comment: Despues de " include_once 'conexion.php'; " abres una llave {, como si fueses a crear una clase, quizás eso es lo que causa el error. Lo probaste y te funcionó?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya vi el error, tienes unas llaves demás en tu código, prueba este.

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once "conexion.php";
    if($_POST['usuario'] == '' or $_POST['password'] == '' or $_POST['repassword'] == '')

    {
        echo 'Por favor llene todos los campos.';
    }
    else
    {
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM usuarios';
        $rec = mysql_query($sql);
        $verificar_usuario = 0;

        while($result = mysql_fetch_object($rec))
        {
            if($result->usuario == $_POST['usuario'])
            {
                $verificar_usuario = 1;
            }
        }

        if($verificar_usuario)
        {
            if($_POST['password'] == $_POST['repassword'])
            {
                $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
                $password = $_POST['password'];
                $sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios (usuario,password) VALUES ('$usuario','$password')";
                mysql_query($sql);

                echo 'Usted se ha registrado correctamente.';
            }
            else
            {
                echo 'Las claves no son iguales, intente nuevamente.';
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'Este usuario ya ha sido registrado anteriormente.';
        }
    }
```

Prueba y comentas que tal.

Comment: Perfecto, solucionado! Lo único ahora me sale un nuevo error... Edito la pregunta.

Comment: Haz una nueva, para que esta se quede registrada, por si le pasa a alguien en un futuro

Comment: Vale, ahora la creo!

Answer (score 0):

El driver mysql_connect() está obsoleto desde PHP 5.5.0 y eliminado desde PHP 7.0.0 Deberías usar el driver mysqli_connect.

http://adodb.org/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=v5:database:mysql